# How can I get the location of an icon in the action menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am developing a tutorial for an application and I need to point at a particular icon in the toolbar.

Here is an extract of the XML for the action menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/AbErase"
    android:title="@string/Erase"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

<item android:id="@+id/AbSuggest"
    android:title="@string/Suggest"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lightbulb_outline_white_48dp"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
<item android:id="@+id/AbUndo"
    android:title="@string/ActionBarUndo"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
    android:orderInCategory="51"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
...
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    isBeingRestored = (savedInstanceState != null);

    Toolbar scToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Sc_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(scToolbar);

    scToolbar.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isBeingRestored) {
                //View mErase = findViewById(R.id.AbErase);
                View mErase = overflowMenu.getItem(0).getActionView();
                int[] location = new int[2];
                mErase.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                eraseIconLeft = location[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

With `View mErase = findViewById(R.id.AbErase);` `mErase` is set to `null`, **** **start EDIT** **** which is not suprising as AbErase is the id of a MenuItem, not the id of a View. **** **end EDIT** ****
With `View mErase = overflowMenu.getItem(0).getActionView();` `location` is set to (0, 24), which is wrong as there already is a logo icon and a title in the toolbar.

How can I get the absolute X coordinate of the `AbErase` view in the toolbar?

**** **EDIT** ****
here is the code where the initialisation of the static variable `overflowMenu` can be found:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    actionBar.collapseActionView();

    overflowMenu = menu;

    isInitializedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.AbInitialized);
    isInitializedMenuItem.setChecked(isInitializeCbxChecked);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code snippet

```
@Nullable 
View getMenuItemView(Toolbar toolbar, @IdRes int menuItemId) throws IllegalAccessException,NoSuchFieldException {
    Field mMenuView = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
    mMenuView.setAccessible(true);
    Object menuView = mMenuView.get(toolbar);
    Field mChildren = menuView.getClass()  //android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView
                          .getSuperclass() //android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                          .getSuperclass() //android.view.ViewGroup
                          .getDeclaredField("mChildren");
    mChildren.setAccessible(true);
    View[] children = (View[]) mChildren.get(menuView);
    for (View child : children) {
        if (child.getId() == menuItemId) {
            return child;
        }                          
    }
    return null;                      
}
```

assuming android.support.v7.widget has been used. The above method would return a View corresponding to you menu item.

```
View menuItemView = getMenuItemView(scToolbar,R.id.AbErase);
int x = menuItemView.getX();
int y = menuItemView.getY();
```

and you have your coordinates.

## EDIT

after a bit more research I found out reflection isn't required.

Before fetching the `menuItemView` we must wait for the `Toolbar` to finish its layout pass

```
scToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            scToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            View menuItem = findViewById(R.id.AbErase);
            if (menuItem != null) {
                int[] location = new int[2];
                menuItem.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                int x = location[0]; //x coordinate
                int y = location[1]; //y coordinate
            }
        }
    });
```

the above snippet is tested to work, it may be placed in any convenient lifecycle callback method.

## EDIT

On looking at the source for the activity the key things that must be remembered is that `View menuItem = findViewById(R.id.AbErase);` should only be called from a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`, `onGlobalLayout` callback.

Comment: I inserted the 3 instructions above relating to `menuItemView` in my Runnable, which should be executed after the toolbar has been laid out if I am not mistaken. After deleting `.getSuperclass() //android.support.v7.internal.widget.LinearLayoutICS` the `menuItemView` is correctly set. However, its Left, Top, Right, Bottom fields are all equal to zero. Is this code executed too early? When should I execute it, assuming that it must be executed before any user interaction?

Comment: @ema3272 which version of android support library are you using? I'll look into the relevant sources to see if I missed anything. 
Technically it should be executed when the views are in a visible state, "onCreate" would be a bit too early for that, try "onResume" that should work.

Comment: sorry for the '.getSuperclass() //android.support.v7.internal.widget.LinearLayoutICS' the 'ActionMenuView' is now a child of 'LinearLayoutCompat' hence the error, edited the answer.

Comment: I use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0          When calling `getMenuItemView(scToolbar,R.id.AbErase)` from `onResume()`, `mMenuView.get(toolbar)` now returns `null`.

Comment: `R.id.AbErase` is the id of a MenuItem, not the id of a View, see the XML in the question. Hence, when I run the code in the EDIT, `findViewById(R.id.AbErase)` returns null.

Comment: I made a sample application to demonstrate the usage of the above code, hope that resolves the issue [Github](https://github.com/sak-venom1997/MenuItemSample)

Comment: Yes your code runs; when I copy it into my application it gives the same result as the code in my question: `location` is set to (0,24). Which means that the menu items seem to be **left-aligned** in the toolbar. However, when the app shows on the device, the menu is **right-aligned**, with an icon and a title on the left side, plus a spinner. Hence the x-coordinate, i.e. location[0] can not be zero. Where has the action bar returned by ´getSupportActionBar()` disappeared?

Comment: Mind sharing the complete code for your activity ? @ema3272

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116129/discussion-between-ema3272-and-sakchham-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` method is too early. The view is not measured yet. Override `onPrepareOptionMenu()` and put your code in it. Also remove your Runnable, its unnecessary.

Comment: I use the Runnable because I find the solution described in [2. Add a runnable to the layout queue: View.post()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) very elegant and performance-oriented. Anyway, when I move the code to `onPrepareOptionMenu` as suggested, `mErase` is `null` whatever the way to initialize it. So this does not work either.